# Use Webpack to Bundle Single Component from package?

Tags: webpack, commonjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to use webpack to bundle one or two components of a large package (react-bootstrap).  I have this in my code:

```
Popover = require('react-bootstrap').Popover;
OverlayTrigger = require('react-bootstrap').OverlayTrigger;
```

I have to use commonjs, but I'm curious if this works better with ES6 `import Popover from 'bootstrap-react'`.  Currently webpack pulls the whole react-bootstrap into my bundle.

How do I get webpack to only bundle those two components and their dependencies?

Comment: have you tried require('react-bootstrap/Popover'); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @4m1r  ?  requiring it like `require('react-bootstrap/Popover');` worked as you suggested.

I decided instead to not include the react-bootstrap popover and instead just detect if it's globally available and if not use a downgraded experience with HTML title attribute.